# OOP Python assigning an object to a tuple from another class

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Calendar with events in python and I was asked to use **Object Oriented Python** without importing any package. I'm new to Python and still trying to learn more and more but I have good knowledge in Java which is an OOP language. I cannot figure out how can I assign an event to a specific date.

This is my Calendar class:

```
class Calendar:

    def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year

     months = [('Jan'), range(1, 32),
               ...
               ('Dec', range(1, 32))
              ]
     days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']

def isLeapYear():
    <<code that will check if the year is a leap year>>

class CalendarView(Calendar):
     def __init__(self, year):
        self.year = year

    def buildYearlyCalendar(self, startDay):
     <<code that displays the calendar>>
```

Above is what I have implemented and it displays the calendar of the year, I will try to make it more specific by defining the month to print later on. The first part works fine just by printing the month and week days. Now I have to implement the function which adds a new event and allocates a time frame to that event. As I mentioned I am new to Python and maybe there will be the need to import a time package to allocate the time to the event or maybe not but we must have created the Calendar by using OOP concepts.

```
class Event(Calendar):
    def __init__(self, day, month, year, time, Event):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.Event = Event

    def addEvent(self, day, month, year, time, Event)
       <<code that I cannot figure out>>
```

In Java that would be like assigning an object to another more specific object but I'm not sure how it works in Python. Should I make the events as tuples too? Or is there another way?

Comment: Why does class `Event` have an `addEvent` method? Is `Event` a single one, or is it a collection of `Event`s?

Comment: @quamrana Well, it should be a collection of `Events` but I'm still not sure how to define it properly or maybe I should make it inside the `Calendar` class

Comment: Your `Calendar` class should have property (some collection, probably `dict` object) that will hold the events. `add_event()` method should be method in `Calendar` class, not `Event` class

Comment: Also having `Event` parameter in the `Event.__init__()` method and then `self.Event = Event` doesn't really make sense too.

Comment: @buran Thank you for the help, so basically I need to create a list of events on the `Calendar` but how do I pair a date for example 19/12/2020 with an event later on the `addEvent` method?

Comment: List of events will not allow to easily access event(s) for specific date. I said a `dict`. The key could be the date of event (as `str`, or `datetime.date` object or timestamp from epoch). The value will be a list, so to allow multiple events in the same day. when you add `event`, you will create the key from event properties and append the new event object. You may also look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: Depending on what functionality you want to achieve, the structure may be more complex, with nested dicts, etc.

Comment: @buran Thank you now I have it more clear. So basically I will have to create a list with events and then add this events to the `dict` with the corresponding date as key. But could it be possible to make nested `dict`'s so I can add time slots in order for not to create an event on the same timeslot? So basically not using lists for the events.

Comment: I already said it could be more complex structure with nested dicts. the most-inner layer should be list, because you may have more than one event in the same slot. Create instance of event, add it to calendar.

Comment: The most inner layer could be dict, if you have some unique id for each event and use it as key.